# Where can I find an RRD file specification?

Tags: database, open-source, binary-files

I'm trying to write a Python program to directly pull information from RRD performance files stored on our servers at work, but the files aren't stored in plaintext format, and I cant find any specification which breaks down the actual format of how RRDtool stores information in an RRD file (ie, the first N bits describe X, the next N bits describe Y, etc).

I know I can use the "fetch" and "dump" utilities of RRDtool to pull a single record, or dump the entire file to a gigantic XML, but I want to try writing something from scratch that will give me more control over how the file is read, and how much space is used (the XML dumps are about 1GB each).

An example of one of the situations I want to be able to address: finding the last time that a server recorded a specific value (ie, the last time it registered greater than a certain number of dropped packets).

I looked online, but everything I find just points back to using RRDtool utilities, rather than any description of how the RRD file itself is formatted.

I apologize if this is the wrong Exchange on which to ask this question; it seemed like the best fit since my question isn't really specific to programming.  I'm also not positive I'm using the best tags for this question, so I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using the JSON export functionality of RRDTool?

You could first export the contents of the RRD file to JSON, which is considerably more lightweight than XML, and then parse it and manipulate it to your liking.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdxport.en.html

Also worth mentioning are some PERL and R packages which might help you achieving your goal.

RRD editor for PERL: `http://search.cpan.org/~dougleith/RRD-Editor/lib/RRD/Editor.pm`
For R: https://github.com/pldimitrov/Rrd

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations; I'll look into JSON (I know nothing of Perl or R).  Also, both of those links are 404 when I try them.

Comment: @Liesmith, I've fixed the links. In your case I'd go with JSON export and then post-processing in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for understanding the binary format of an RRD file is to download the RDDTool source code from https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/download.en.html and reverse engineer the file specification from the source file rrd_fetch.c.

If you want an overview of the structure of RRD XML please refer to https://serverfault.com/questions/287829/where-documentation-of-rrddump-xml-format-is

After you've done the hard work you could post a summary of your findings here :).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and look into it sometime. My knowledge of C is virtually null, but it may give some clues.  If so, I'll update my original question...but don't expect anything to be completed too swiftly in that regard...